# Convert local-name() from MSSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xml, xpath

I'm working on migrating some codes from MSSQL to MySQL, but I don't know the equivalent of local-name()in MySQL.

The original MSSQL code is as followed:

```
with cte as (select convert(xml,'<Attributes>
    <Map>
        <entry key="trigger" value = "action">
            <value>
                <Map>
                    <entry key=" Processing">
                        <value>
                            <Boolean>true</Boolean>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                </Map>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </Map>
</Attributes>') as attributes)
select entr.value('@key','nvarchar(100)') AS AttrKey
      ,entr.value('@value','nvarchar(500)') AS AttrValue
      ,HasValueElement.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(100)') AS ValueType
FROM cte a1
cross apply a1.attributes.nodes(N'/Attributes/Map/entry') A(entr)
OUTER APPLY A.entr.nodes(N'value/*') B(HasValueElement)
```

The output is:
AttrKey ||AttrValue ||ValueType
Trigger ||Action    ||Map

1. How we can apply similar to local-name() in MySQL to return the ValueType = "Map"? When I tried something like "//*[local-name()]" in MySQL, it returned error.
2. And what is the "." in "local-name(.)" meaning?

Really appreciate your support.

TIA

Comment: FWIW, `local-name()` is an XQuery function, it's not specific to SQL Server.  According to the MySQL 8.0 docs, it's not supported or has known issues.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html

Comment: The `.` refers to the current node, so `local-name(.)` returns the name of the current node, for example `Boolean`